# SQL (Redshift) to get the intersect of multiple tables

Tags: amazon-redshift, intersect

I'm using Redshift and have 6 tables of IDs in. I want to get the intersect between each of the tables.

So my final output would look something like this:

- Table 1 & Table 2 have 10% common IDs
- Table 1 & Table 3 have 50% common IDs
- .....
- .....
- Table 6 & Table 4 have 20% common IDs
- Table 6 & Table 5 have 3% common IDs

I can easily get the data, but it would be a lot of repeating the same SQL, so I've tried to create some tables of all the IDs and tables they are in but I'm stuck as to what to get the data in one or two SQL's.

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to full join all these tables by ID in a subquery and then use conditional aggregate so that `Table 1 & Table 2 have 10% common IDs` would be expressed as

`100.0*sum(case when id1 is not null and id2 is not null then 1 end)/count(id1)`

(taking Table 1 row count as denominator)

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much what I did in the end